# aws cli has no output

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I've been using aws cli on this laptop for a while to interact with s3 buckets. Suddenly, the tool has stopping printing any output whatsoever:

```
C:\>aws

C:\>aws --debug

C:\>aws --help

C:\>where aws
C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\aws
C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\aws.cmd
```

This is in an administrator command prompt, but it's the same in an admin powershell prompt. Windows version 10.0.18362 Build 18362 - I took the anniversary update a few weeks ago but am not sure if it's correlated or not.

aws cli on my other (Win 10, anniversary update) machine, using the same authentication, works fine.

I've tried straight-up uninstalling and reinstalling aws cli, but after the reinstall I can't even get it to print anything to authenticate me.

Any ideas? Any more information I can give you?

Comment: This would suggest something is accepting standard output when running the AWS cli. Can you get standout when the echo command is executed? Are the commands successful even without the output?

Comment: the commands are not successful. do you mean `echo aws --debug`? that echos "aws" and "--debug" on to their own lines.

Comment: What happens when you run `doskey /MACROS:ALL` ? The behavior suggests the AWS cli is writing to `NUL` . I can reproduce the behavior by running `aws --help > NUL 2>&1`

Comment: @jmp I get no output from doskey /MACROS:ALL, nor from `aws --version` after running doskey.

Answer (score 23):

For anyone stumbling across this, it seems that certain v2 versions (`2.2.7` in my case) fail silently if `less` isn't installed.

In these cases, setting `AWS_PAGER` to an empty string should fix the problem.

Later AWS CLI versions (e.g. `2.2.18`) are decidedly more helpful:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity

Unable to redirect output to pager. Received the following error when opening pager:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'less'

Learn more about configuring the output pager by running "aws help config-vars".
```

Comment: Thank you, `export AWS_PAGER=""` did the trick!

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same issue.
It was like:

```
$aws sts get-caller-identity

Unable to redirect output to pager. Received the following error when opening pager:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'less'

Learn more about configuring the output pager by running "aws help config-vars".
```

And the solution is `yum install less` or `apt-get install less`. After that, it will show the proper status, like:

```json
{
    "UserId": "AIDASAMPLEUSERID",
    "Account": "123456789012",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/DevAdmin"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and for me the solution was to install version 2 of aws cli.

From the quick read it might have been caused by `Python` and `aws` version dependency mismatch.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to solve this issue is by piping the output to `cat`.

Take your command `aws sts get-caller-identity` and add `| cat`

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity | cat =
```

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu and Linux users

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -yy less
```